# Call schema method without create a new Model object with Nodejs/Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My problem is that I want to update a user password that's already stored on MongoDB, and I can't call a method for `User`. Let me show the code:

User schema:

```
userSchema = new Schema({ ... });

userSchema.methods.setPassword = function (passwordPlainText) {
    this.passwordHash = createHash(passwordPlainText, this.salt);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

And it works fine if I made this:

```
user = new User();
user.setPassword('foobar');
```

But if I want to do something like this:

```
User.findOne({email: req.param('email')}, function (err, user) {
    user.setPassword('foobar');
});
```

It outputs:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setPassword'
```

Can someone please help me to find a way to call these schema methods after retrieving the user from database?

Additional info:

- node v0.8.4
- express v3.0.4
- mongoose module (http://mongoosejs.com/)

Comment: Found the problem, seems that the user I was saving in the session didn't persists the schema methods for user.
Solved the problem saving just the userId in the session, calling another User.findOne(id) and then calling setPassword method.

Comment: Anyone knows a better solution? Thanks.

Comment: Hm... works for me using the syntax `User.method('auth', ...` without any special hacks. The syntax shouldn't matter though. Which version of mongoose are you using (i have 3.5.9)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, seems that the user I was saving in the session didn't persists the schema methods for user. Solved the problem saving just the userId in the session, calling another User.findOne(id) and then calling setPassword method.